# Для чего нужны параметры noise и random_state функции make_moons?

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Не пойму предназначение параметров noise и random_state в следующем коде. Код из Python:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, noise=0.25, random_state=3)
```

Comment: А документацию читать вы пробовали?

Comment: не нашел материал по этим параметрам

Comment: Запрос "sklearn make_moons" и первая ссылка о них рассказывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта функция генерирует наборы точек такие, что в проекции на ось *Oxy* получаются две половинки окружности, одна вложенные в другую. Параметр `noise` представляет собой *σ* в следующей формуле плотности вероятности [гауссового шума](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_noise). Чем он меньше, тем меньше точки отклоняются от своих положенных мест. Параметр `random_state` должен быть либо числом — инициализационным зерном ГПСЧ, либо сам должен является ГПСЧ. Имеет значение, только если задаётся уровень шума, или параметр `shuffle` истинен. Чуть подробнее [см. в документации](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_moons.html).

[image: p_G(z) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ -\frac{(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }]

Вот какие картинки можно увидеть, при разных *σ*.

[image: sigma = None, 0.01, 0.1, 0.25, 0.66, 1]

<sup>[Код генерации](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25313348/)</sup>